System.BadImageFormatException with MetaQuotes.MT5ManagerAPI64.dll in .NET 8 Docker Container
I am running a .NET 8 application inside a Docker container, but I am encountering the following error when the application tries to load MetaQuotes.MT5ManagerAPI64.dll:

Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load
file or assembly '/app/MetaQuotes.MT5ManagerAPI64.dll'. An attempt was
made to load a program with an incorrect format. File name:
'/app/MetaQuotes.MT5ManagerAPI64.dll'

The DLL is a native library provided by MetaQuotes, specifically MetaQuotes.MT5ManagerAPI64.dll.
My application works correctly on my local machine (Windows) but fails when running inside the Docker container.
I suspect the issue is related to architecture mismatches.
# Base image for running the application
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080

# Build stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src

COPY MyProject/MyApp/MyApp.csproj MyApp/
COPY MyProject/MyAuth/MyAuth.csproj MyAuth/
COPY MyProject/MyModels/MyModels.csproj MyModels/

COPY MyProject/ExternalLibraries/MyNativeLibrary/ ExternalLibraries/MyNativeLibrary/

RUN dotnet restore "MyApp/MyApp.csproj"

COPY MyProject/ .

WORKDIR "/src/MyApp"
RUN dotnet build "MyApp.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build -p:PlatformTarget=x64
RUN dotnet publish "MyApp.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish -p:PlatformTarget=x64 /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
COPY MyProject/ExternalLibraries/MyNativeLibrary/ ExternalLibraries/MyNativeLibrary/

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]


Application Configuration: The .csproj file explicitly targets x64:
<PropertyGroup>     <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>     <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework> </PropertyGroup> 

What could be causing this System.BadImageFormatException? Is there any specific configuration or dependency required to load this native DLL in a Linux-based .NET environment? How can I ensure that the DLL is loaded correctly?
I expected the application to run inside the Docker container without throwing a System.BadImageFormatException, successfully loading the MyNativeLibrary64.dll during initialization.
However, despite these steps, the error persists. I need guidance on what might be missing or incorrectly configured to resolve this issue.

If the native DLL works locally on your Windows machine, that means it's a Windows file and it's not going to just work on Linux. You would need a Linux version of that file. Otherwise, you'd need to run it on Windows containers.
